# Get function handle of fit function in matlab and assign fit parameters

Tags: matlab, handle, curve-fitting

I'm fitting custom functions to my data.
After obtaining the fit I would like to get something like a function handle of my fit function including the parameters set to the ones found by the fit.
I know I can get the model with

```
formula(fit)
```

and I can get the parameters with

```
coeffvalues(fit)
```

but is there any easy way to combine the two in one step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This little loop will do the trick:

```
x = (1:100).';  %'
y = 1*x.^5 + 2*x.^4 + 3*x.^3 + 4*x.^2 + 5*x + 6;
fitobject = fit(x,y,'poly5');  

cvalues = coeffvalues(fitobject);
cnames = coeffnames(fitobject);
output = formula(fitobject);

for ii=1:1:numel(cvalues)
    cname = cnames{ii};
    cvalue = num2str(cvalues(ii));
    output = strrep(output, cname , cvalue);
end

output = 1*x^5 + 2*x^4 + 3*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 5*x + 6
```

The loop needs to be adapted to the number of coefficients of your fit.

Edit: two slight changes in order to fully answer the question.

```
fhandle = @(x) eval(output)
```

returns a function handle. Secondly output as given by your procedure doesn't work, as the power operation reads .^ instead of x, which can obviously be replaced by

```
strrep(output, '^', '.^');
```

Comment: Thanks, nice answer, I used it as the basis of a script I was writing. There are a couple minor improvements that can be made (e.g., to allow it to work with different functions fitted, like exponential, etc.): the coefficient names can be found with `coeffnames(fitobject)`, and the number of coefficients to iterate over can be found with `length(coeff)` (or a variety of other fields available).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Matlab curve fitting function, `polyfit`.

```
p = polyfit(x,y,n)
```

So, `p` contains the coefficients of the polynomial, `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the function you're trying to fit. `n` is the order of the polynomial. For example, `n=1` is linear, `n=2` is quadratic, etc. For more info, see this [documentation centre](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) link. The only issue is that you may not want a polynomial fit, in which case you'll have to use different method.

Oh, and you can use the calculated coefficients `p` to to re-evaluate the polynomial with:

```
f = polyval(p,x);
```

Here, `f` is the value of the polynomial with coefficients `p` evaluated at points `x`.

Comment: I think the OP was asking about properties of a `fit` object, from the Curve Fitting Toolbox (see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/fit.html).

Comment: Yeah, I basically would like to use a function like the polyval() one , but for a custom model.