# How to solve a matlab fit?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

So I want to solve a plot fit for several points, but the problem, that I am facing right now is, that my fit object `fit_eq` is a `char` but solve needs a `sym`. I searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution how to fix this. Here is my code, I cut unimportant parts, and some variables are german words, so don't get confused. `gesamt` is a 60x20 matrix, where every odd column is the same (it's made out of 10 matrices which are an outcome of a meassurement).

```
anzahlproben = 10;
for i = 1:2:anzahlproben*2 
   probe = gesamt(:,i:i+1); 
   [row c]=find(probe==0); 
   row(1:2,:)=[]; 
   for j=row
      probe(j,:)=[];
   end
   N22_{(i+1)/2} = probe;
end

for i = 1:1:anzahlproben
    x = N22_{i}(1:1:size(N22_{i},1),1);
    y = N22_{i}(1:1:size(N22_{i},1),2);
    ft = fittype('poly9');
    fitobject_{i}=fit(x,y,ft);
end

cvalues = coeffvalues(fitobject_{1});
cnames = coeffnames(fitobject_{1});
fit_eq = formula(fitobject_{1});
for ii=1:1:numel(cvalues)
    cname = cnames{ii};
    cvalue = num2str(cvalues(ii));
    fit_eq = strrep(fit_eq, cname , cvalue);
end
y=1;
syms x
erg = (solve(fit_eq == y,x))
```

I got the last part from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478077/get-function-handle-of-fit-function-in-matlab-and-assign-fit-parameters#18858467) and gives an equation in a `char`.

Matlab gives the output:

```
erg =

Empty sym: 0-by-1
```

Which can't be right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the *first* line of the doc:

> Support for character vector or string inputs has been removed.
>   Instead, use syms to declare variables and replace inputs such as
>   solve('2*x == 1','x') with solve(2*x == 1,x).

So `eqn` should be of class `sym` not a string!

Try:

```
erg = solve(str2sym(fit_eq) == y,x)
```

If it still don't work either your equation is wrong or you've not declared the symbolic variables involved in your equation.